# Connecting applications with Tethering in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, vcl, subnet, tethering

I am trying to connect two applications with Tethering one VCL (server) and the other Android (client) using AutoConnect (TimeOut and Target):

```
...
TCarton.AutoConnect(2000, '192.168.5.0');
...
```

But when connecting the client (Android) I receive an exception:

> Debugger Exception Notification: Project CartonBingo.apk raised
>   exception class EIdMCastNotValidAddress with message 'The supplied IP
>   address is not a valid multicast address.'.

Comment: Have you read http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Connecting_to_Remote_Applications_Using_App_Tethering and downloaded the examples to see how it should work?

Comment: App Tethering *does* use Indy. IIPMulitcastClient is used in System.Tether.Comm, and the implementor is TIPMulticastClientPeer, in the IPPeerClient unit. According to the help: "For network adapters, ATargetList can be a list of IP adresses or subnets". For the overload being used here, it's a single IP address. Having said all that, yes.. there's a distinct lack of code. It would be more helpful to have a [mcve]

Comment: @Dave You are right, I should have looked in `IPPeerClient`(or `IPPeerServer`). Sorry for the noise.

Comment: I was wondering if you found a solution to this, I am facing the same issue.
As I'm not really familiar with Indy, Googling IPPeerClient has not helped me.